# Obtaining Crash Reports

Tags: xcode, developer-program

I have an app in the App store. A user has told me that she submitted a crash report but the Crashes tab in Xcode is empty.

As a paid developer, how do I access this performance / crash data?

Comment: Have you looked at https://appstoreconnect.apple.com/?

Comment: yes, zero crashes